# Error while calling myCtrl.sink.addError in myCtrl.stream.listen

Tags: flutter

I am new to Bloc pattern and Stream. While creating bloc i got following log:

```
E/flutter (18086): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: ss
E/flutter (18086): null
```

You can reproduce this

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter test 2',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  StreamController<String> ctrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    ctrl = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
    ctrl.stream.listen((value){
      ctrl.addError(value);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: ctrl.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return TextField(
                onChanged: ctrl.sink.add,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  errorText: snapshot.error,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    ctrl.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

So basically I am validating the TextField input. I am sending data in through `sink.add` and validating in `stream.listen` and sending error back by `sink.addError`

I verified that on calling `sink.addError`, the  `stream.listen` won't get called. So no loop will occur.

Am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the StreamSubscription created from the .listen() method. The StreamSubscription doesn't know how to handle the error so it just shows it to you.

To prevent the error from displaying, provide it with an onError function so that it knows what to do. Do this either while you're calling the listen method or assign it to the StreamSubscription that it returns.

```
ctrl.stream.listen((value){
  ctrl.addError(value);
}, onError: (_) {
  //insert code here
});
```

Documentation: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-async/Stream/listen.html

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the error is coming from StreamBuilder. But it is actually from the listen method. Still why cannot they just ignore the onError callback if it is not provided. Do I have to give empty callback for onError, onDone for every listen method of that stream?

Comment: Think of the onError method like the catch block in the try - catch block. While yes, they could just ignore the error thrown, but doing so might cause an error to go unhandled. So they just default with no implementation. Yes, it can just be an empty callback.